# How to add pixels to a variable?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var subarticlemargintop = $("#article").height();
    $("#subarticle").css("margin-top",subarticlemargintop);
});
```

How can I add 5px to the variable?

Comment: You want `subarticlemargintop+5` ?

Comment: $("#subarticle").css("margin-top",subarticlemargintop + 5 + 'px');

Comment: @Ramunas No need for the `px` : it's the default unit.

Comment: `subarticlemargintop` is a number. You can use *addition* to increase the number. This is done with the [*addition operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators). For example: `var new_number = subarticlemargintop + 5;`.

Comment: @TelmoMarques then 99% of all websites will break

Comment: @TelmoMarques I hope you're joking. Right ?

Comment: @TelmoMarques also, it would be an incompatible change that goes against the current documentation for no good reason

Comment: However unlikely it may be, it's **always** better to specify **exacty** what you want. Most of the discrepancies we found on the web are due to "no need, it's the default behaviour".

Comment: @JanDvorak "then 99% of all websites will break" exactly my point. You don't rely on default behavior so that you'll be part to of the 1%.

Comment: WHOA!! A question abt how to do addition in JS!! `:O` Well Ive seen everything now.

Comment: @TelmoMarques relying on the documentation, however, is perfectly fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, relying on documentation it's the best bet to make sure everything works correctly. But it changes, things evolve. On the other hand `1px` will always be `1px`. There's no way to control everything that may change in the future, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't control the aspects that can be controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#subarticle").css("margin-top", subarticlemargintop + 5);
```

Obvious when you know!

Comment: I researched this and all I found was applying parseInt() and placing "+ 5" in every possible place **but** there. I feel like an idiot, lol. Thanks, works great!

Comment: The easiest way is to run `typeof $("#article").height();` to see what that returns. If it were a string you'd want to apply `parseInt`, otherwise, not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var subarticlemargintop = $("#article").height();
        $("#subarticle").css("margin-top", subarticlemargintop + 5);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var subarticlemargintop = $("#article").css("margin-top");
$("#subarticle").css("margin-top", subarticlemargintop + 5);
```